# ng-repeat conflics with jQuery function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, material-design

I combined AngularJS and [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) and use ng-repeat to render images. MaterializeCSS includes the jQuery-based `materiabox` function to execute an animation to open a [modal](http://materializecss.com/media.html) for each element with the `materialbox` class.

The modal can't be opened by clicking. If I display a single image without ng-repeat it works fine.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span class="col m6 l4">
        <li ng-repeat="url in imageUrls">
            <img class="materialboxed" ng-src="{{ url }}">
        </li>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.imageUrls = ["https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/179234/screenshots/1958409/screen_shot_2015-03-04_at_14.58.59.png", "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/5276/screenshots/1958408/booze_cruise_icon_kendrickkidd.jpg"];
});


// Code from MaterializeCSS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
});
```

Comment: Nobody is going to go and look at your demo code, esp. if it's not a link. Post the **relevant** code here.

Comment: I added excerpts of my code regarding the HTML and JS.

Comment: did you add the initialization code that is listed on the documentation page for when you add images dynamically?

Comment: On the docs of AngularJS or MaterializeCSS (for jQuery)?

Comment: the initialization code on the page you linked http://materializecss.com/media.html

Comment: I did, but nothing changed. I copied a snippet for a material box from the docs and placed it outside of ng-repeat and it worked.

Comment: I don't know the *exact* initialization order of these scripts, but it would seem that `ng-src` is the culprit here, as it's purpose is to generate the `src=` tag **after** the expression has been evaluated.  I would imagine that at the time that materializeCSS initializes, there is no `src` in the element yet.

Comment: to that end, I suspect you would have to wrap this in a directive where you can control when the `materialbox` script gets initialized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73022/discussion-between-user3147268-and-claies).

Comment: I simplified the code. The ng-src directive works with MaterializeCSS if I display a single image without ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i had the same problem , the solution is put the jquery code into a angularjs directive , some like:

Javascript

```
yourApp.directive('theNameOfYourDirective', function() {
return {
    // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
    restrict: 'A',
    // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
    link: function() {
        $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    }
   };
 });
```

and for the html code ,put the name of the directive like a attr of the tag:

HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<span class="col m6 l4">
    <li ng-repeat="url in imageUrls" theNameOfYourDirective>
        <img class="materialboxed" ng-src="{{ url }}">
    </li>
</span>
```

this works for me, greetings
reference : https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/