# ng-source and materializecss materialbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, materialize

I have a `flask` app and I'm using `angularjs` along with the [`materializecss`](http://materializecss.com/) at the front end. In that app there is a gallery in which I would like to use [`materialbox`](http://materializecss.com/media.html) with it. If images are loading dynamically the `materialbox` won't trigger properly.

I have found a possible duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062122/ng-repeat-conflics-with-jquery-function-call), but unfortunately, that didn't work.

*app.js*

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{${');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}$}');

        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/main_page.html',
                controller  : 'ListUrlController'
            })

            // route for the gallery page
            .when('/download/:threadUrl?', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/gallery_show.html',
                controller  : 'FormController'
            });

    });
```

*showgallery.html* **not working**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="image_list in images" ng-show="ImageExists">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3" ng-repeat="image in image_list">
        <img ng-src="{${ image.t_image }$}" class="responsive-img materialboxed" width="250">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
</script>
```

but this **works**(hard coding the image urls)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/ac7a/i/2014/279/d/f/lionel_messi_by_anaaospedacos-d800pg8.png" class="responsive-img materialboxed" width="250">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/ac7a/i/2014/279/d/f/lionel_messi_by_anaaospedacos-d800pg8.png" class="responsive-img materialboxed" width="250">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/ac7a/i/2014/279/d/f/lionel_messi_by_anaaospedacos-d800pg8.png" class="responsive-img materialboxed" width="250">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/ac7a/i/2014/279/d/f/lionel_messi_by_anaaospedacos-d800pg8.png" class="responsive-img materialboxed" width="250">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
</script>
```

but this also throwing some exception in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined`

So please tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: i did this .. and it worked for me .. 

     `app.directive('loadImages', function() {
      return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).materialbox();
       }
      };
      });`